# Opencart Display subcategories

Tags: php, opencart

on each products page I currently have displayed the products subcategory, but only one level deep. So if in categories I have `Brother > MFC > B4564 > TN450`.... and I am on the TN450's product page, down below it will only show `BN4564` . I need it also show The `mfc` and the `brother` part. I am not sure how to do this.. any ideas? here is my current code.

.TPL file

```
  <!-- Display product categories -->  

 <?php foreach ($catprod as $catp) 
 { 

    ?><a href="<?php echo $catp['href']; ?>"><?php echo $catp['name']; ?>  </a><?php 

 }`
```

controller .php file

```
$data['catprod'] = array();
$product_category = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($this->request->get['product_id']);

foreach ($product_category as $prodcat) 
{
    $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($prodcat['category_id']);
    if ($category_info) 
    {
        $data['catprod'][] = array('name' => $category_info['description'],'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id']));
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

which version of opencart?
this should work for version 1:
open `catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/category.tpl`
remove its contents and insert:

```
        <div class="box" id="categories-menu">
        <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
        <div class="box-content">
<ul class="box-category" id="box-category">
  <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
  <li>
    <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active list-group-item"  ><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="list-group-item" style = "font-weight: normal;"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
      <li>
        <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?> class="list-group-item"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="list-group-item"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
      </li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
  </li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using version 2.0.x. Thanks ill take  a look at it!